# How to display error messages inside modal on click of td element?

Tags: jquery

As of now, on click of view errors of any td element as shown in the picture, it is showing the same errors for every td element  in the modal. It is taking the last value of error messages in the loop and displaying the same in the modal , if I click on any td element- view errors.

How should I display the correct error messages in the modal of every td element?

```
function ValidateBulkdata() {
    var tbody = $('#tblCsvRecords tbody'),
        props = ["Type", "Code", "ControlNumber",
            "Province", "Name", "CName"
        ];

    $.each(globalfiledata, function(key, value) {
        var tr = $('<tr>');
        var isError = false;

        $.each(props, function(key, prop) {
            $('<td>').html(value[prop]).appendTo(tr);
        });

        var td = $('<td>');
        var isError = false;
        var errorMessage = "";

        if ((value.Phone.length) > 20) {
            isError = true;
            errorMessage += "Enter a valid Phone";
            errorMessage += "<br>";
        }
        if ((value.Quantity.length) > 10) {
            isError = true;
            errorMessage += "Quantity should be of maximum length 10";
            errorMessage += "<br>";
        }
        if (isError) {
            var link = td.append('<a href="#" id="OpenPopup" class="details">View Errors</a>');
            $('<img>').attr('src', '/assets/images/error_red.jpg').wrap(link).appendTo(td);
            $(document).on('click', '#OpenPopup', function() {
                showErrorMessage(errorMessage); //need todo something here
            });
        } else {
            $('<img>').attr('src', '/assets/images/success_green.png').appendTo(td);
            bulksave.push(value);
        }
        td.appendTo(tr);
        tbody.append(tr);
    });
}

function showErrorMessage(errorMessage) {
    $('#divShipmentValidation').modal('show');
    $('#divShipmentValidation .modal-body').html(errorMessage);
    $("#divShipmentValidation .modal-body").css("color", "red");
}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but it can help: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add all errors messages inside some element and make that hidden . Then , when *view_errors* link gets clicked simply get reference of the element where error are there and use `.html()` then pass same to your `showErrorMessage()` function .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//suppose data look like this..
var globalfiledata = [{
  "Phone": {
    "length": 11
  },
  "Quantity": {
    "length": 23
  },
  "Type": "n",
  "Code": 1,
  "ControlNumber": 13,
  "Province": "na",
  "Name": "si",
  "CName": "de"
}, {
  "Phone": {
    "length": 23
  },
  "Quantity": {
    "length": 23
  },
  "Type": "nabc",
  "Code": 2,
  "ControlNumber": 13,
  "Province": "na",
  "Name": "swati",
  "CName": "de"
}]
ValidateBulkdata()

function ValidateBulkdata() {
  var tbody = $('#tblCsvRecords tbody'),
    props = ["Type", "Code", "ControlNumber",
      "Province", "Name", "CName"
    ];

  $.each(globalfiledata, function(key, value) {
    var tr = $('<tr>');
    var isError = false;

    $.each(props, function(key, prop) {
      $('<td>').html(value[prop]).appendTo(tr);
    });

    var td = $('<td>');
    var isError = false;
    var errorMessage = "";
    if ((value.Phone.length) > 20) {
      isError = true;
      errorMessage += "Enter a valid Phone <br/>";
    }
    if ((value.Quantity.length) > 10) {
      isError = true;
      errorMessage += "Quantity should be of maximum length 10 <br/>";
    }
    if (isError) {
      //add span and put error inside that.. use class aas well
      var link = td.append('<span class="errors">' + errorMessage + '</span><a href="#" class="OpenPopup" class="details">View Errors</a>');
      $('<img>').attr('src', '/assets/images/error_red.jpg').wrap(link).appendTo(td)
    } else {
      $('<img>').attr('src', '/assets/images/success_green.png').appendTo(td);
      //bulksave.push(value);
    }
    td.appendTo(tr);
    tbody.append(tr);
  });
}

function showErrorMessage(errorMessage) {
  $('#divShipmentValidation').modal('show');
  $('#divShipmentValidation .modal-body p').html(errorMessage);
  $("#divShipmentValidation .modal-body p").css("color", "red");
}
//onclick of view error
$(document).on('click', '.OpenPopup', function() {
  showErrorMessage($(this).prev().html()); //get prev elements htmls 
});
```

```css
.errors {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="tblCsvRecords">
  <thead>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Code</th>
    <th>ControlNumber</th>
    <th>Province</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>CName</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="modal fade" id="divShipmentValidation" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```